# ViewPager2 колбек следующей страницы

Tags: java, android, kotlin

У меня есть `ViewPager2` с фотками, он постепенно заполняется фотками из галереи, их так-же можно удалять. Когда я перехожу на следующую страницу `ViewPager2`, то мне требуется обновить интерфейс.

Вот как я этого добился

```
val onPageChangeCallback = object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            if (position >= 0) {
                updateUI()
            }
            super.onPageSelected(position)
        }
    }

viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(onPageChangeCallback)
```

Всё бы ничего, но есть некоторая проблема.

Есть предположим три фотки. И тут я начинаю их удалять с первого элемента, тем самым `onPageSelected()` не работает, потому что якобы мы не перелистываем страницу а просто вторая страница стала первой.

Был бы рад если кто нибудь бы предложил альтернативные варианты, или решение на текущем варианте.

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем хорошо понимаю конкретно ваш кейс. Что именно вы обновляете в методе `updateUi()`. Но вы можете подписаться на изменение данных в адаптере:

```
pagerAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            override fun onChanged() {
                super.onChanged()
            }

            override fun onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
                super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount)
            }

            override fun onItemRangeMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int, itemCount: Int) {
                super.onItemRangeMoved(fromPosition, toPosition, itemCount)
            }

            override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)
            }

            override fun onItemRangeChanged(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
                super.onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount)
            }

            override fun onItemRangeChanged(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int, payload: Any?) {
                super.onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount, payload)
            }
        })
```

И в одном из колбеков вызывать ваш `updateUi()`.

Но если честно я не совсем уверен в том, что это именно то что вам нужно. Возможно если у вас на каждой страницу есть свой экран со своей логикой вам стоит подумать о том, чтоб сделать внутри `Pager-а` в качестве элемента `Fragment` так вам будет проще обрабатывать его жизненный цикл и соответственно обновлять Ui.